# A chat program. What security solutions can I use?

Tags: delphi, security, indy

I am working on an chat program with socket programming (Indy in Delphi).

What security solutions can I use to satisfy its security? From user authentication (I used a server to authenticate users) and type of packets security that can be used?

I don't have any idea what can make my app vulnerable.

Comment: check out http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/dcpcrypt, maybe roll your own IOHandler that will encrypt/decrypt data on the fly?

Comment: Indy supports OpenSSL so yo only need to add and configure a OpenSSL handler, and make sure that the firewall allows connections over the secure port

Answer (score 6):

Indy supports OpenSSL so yo only need to add and configure a OpenSSL handler, and make sure that the firewall allows connections over the secure port.

A popular source of information is the Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP).

Their pages include lots of technical article, for example

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Vulnerability

about vulnerabilities